# Resizing a Tab Control header

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I'm owner drawing a Tab Control. I need to use a significantly larger font than the default windows font for my purposes, and if the Tab Control SizeMode is TabSizeMode.Normal, it's supposed to auto re-size to the size of its contents. This works well, except for when I change the actual font of the control.

I've tried:

1. Changing the TabControl font
2. Changing the TabPage font
3. Using TextRenderer.MeasureString and Changing the TabPage Width property

However, nothing seems to work that will change the size of the tab item header.

Segoe UI (8)
http://puu.sh/21GZo/1e986a45a6

And when I make the font larger (I'm custom drawing the font with graphics.DrawString)

Segoe UI (15)
http://puu.sh/21H1m/a45ae2e1f3

The header size doesn't accommodate for the new width of the text.

Comment: This should answer the question, and is perhaps a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349133/tabcontrol-tab-headings-resize-when-changing-font

Comment: I agree, that question covers it.

Comment: winforms doesn't support customization. the example you linked to can be done with 5 lines of XAML in WPF and 0 lines of code. Also, whatever content you place inside the header (not limited to text) will cause the header to auto size itself, not requiring to do a bunch of HACKs like winforms.

Comment: @JABFreeware the ItemSize property resizes every header in the tab control. I need to resize specific headers.

Comment: @cloud again, if you need a professional-looking UI you need WPF. winforms is not going to provide that without tons of code.

Comment: @HighCore Since your first comment I've been reading up on WPF. It's very different. I'm still interested in knowing a windows forms solution (even if it takes lots of code) because that's what the project I'm working on is. 

Do you have any reading material you suggest for a first-time WPFer who wants to skin his controls?

Comment: @cloud [TabControl Style Tutorial](http://blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/01/25/TabControlStyling_PartOne.aspx)